# Angular 2 CLI - Deployment

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-cli

I have built an Angular 2 application using the Angular 2 CLI.  My issue is now I want to deploy the application to a local server as a staging environment for others to view.

Most tutorials that use the Angular 2 CLI show a `dist` folder that appears to have been generated when the project was first created using the CLI.  I can only generate the `dist` folder using `ng build`.  I assume the Angular 2 CLI changed where initially the `dist` folder was part of the initial folder structure, but now it is only generated when using `ng build`?

As a test, I copied the generated `dist` folder into the `www` folder of the WAMP server [http://localhost:8080/Project/dist/] to try and run the application...  The browser console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)      http://localhost:8080/inline.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)      http://localhost:8080/bundle.js
```

It is looking for all assets at the root of the local server, rather than setting the root to the location of the index.html within the `dist` folder.  All images and icons have the same problem...  I figure I have failed to configure something for the relative paths...  What do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you can specify the output path of the `ng build` command - so no manual copying needed. Eg.: `ng build --output-path /var/www/app_foo/root/`.

Second, there is a *base path* concept implemented as *base tag* in `index.html` - `<base href="/path">`. You can set it manually or during building via `ng build --base-href /path/`.

In your case it seems it should match: `ng build --base-href /Project/dist/`.

Comment: Perfect.  Worked a charm.