# Angular-CLI - how to append a prefix to script tag on index.html

Tags: build, angular-cli

Angular-cli is generating the index.html file during ng-build.

The app runs on a hardware proxy, meaning that all of it's script tags need to be prefixed with "/some/prefix/". The cli generates the following script tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.b1a79a362dfcae386d67.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.2b9bcc2dcbe5c9cb526b.bundle.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to prefix the src of each tag with something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 CLI - Deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167524/angular-2-cli-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `--base-href` when serving or building, e.g. `ng serve --base-href '/some/prefix/' --aot`.

`--base-href` sets the `<base href='/some/prefix'>` tag in your HTML file and adds such prefix to all scripts and stylesheets that are automatically defined.

Note, however, that setting the `base` tag manually will **not** have the same effect and that will be overwritten every time you build your application.